# Load a form action in a div on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dealer locator which is powered through software that our IT department manages, and I'm trying to fix up their code a bit and make it more user friendly.

What I'd like to do is allow end users to enter in their zip code, and have the list of dealers in their area show up on the same page, rather than open a new tab/window, or re-load the page.

```
<div class="locator">
    <form method="get" id="dsearchform" action="http://www5.pacelink.com/paceweb/locatorframe.jsp?brand=SWEQ&zip=&&distance=50&numlocations=6&submit=Find+a+Dealer" target="_blank" alt="Pace Search - Sno-Way" onsubmit="return dsearch(this)" class="dealersearch">
        <input type="hidden" name="locatorBrand" value="SWEQ" />
        <input type="hidden" name="distance" value="100" /><input type="hidden" name="numlocations" value="6" />
        <h2>Sno-Way Dealer Locator:</h2>
        <h3 class="secondary">Enter your zip code below to find an authorized Sno-Way dealer near you!</h3>
        <div class="zip-entry">
        <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="ZipCode" value="ZipCode" class="field" onfocus="if(this.value == 'ZipCode'){this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='ZipCode';}"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" id="button" class="but"/>
        </div>
    </form>     
</div>
```

I've cobbled this together from another solution posted here, but I don't think it's on the right track at all:

```
<div id="search">
    <form id="try" method="post" target="receiver" action="http://www5.pacelink.com/paceweb/locatorframe.jsp?brand=SWEQ&zip=&&distance=50&numlocations=6&submit=Find+a+Dealer">
       Zip: <input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'ZipCode'){this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='ZipCode';}"/>
       <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id="receiver">
        <?php if (isset($_POST['zip'])){
                  //display search results here.
              }
        ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @DCruz22 I started fiddling around with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263887/set-div-as-target-container-for-result-page-of-a-post-method

But I don't think that's setting out to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'll add what I've cobbled together so far to my original post, it's too long for the comment box.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). Post what you try and what errors you get in your question.

Comment: Or else, if it applies to your use case, try using an `iframe`. You can set your `form` to show the result action in any `iframe` on the page.

Answer (score 0):

First of
If you want to change the html dynamically you need to go with JavaScript and AJAX. This is , you load stuff asynchronously. The comment states XHR, this is

```
XmlHttpRequest
```

Better directly look for the much more convenient JQuery Ajax function.
Jquery is very easy to use.
Example to set html of the container with id retailer

```
$('#retailer').html(response); // response is the html your php creates
```

You only need to fetch the html via jquery ajax({... }), where most of the stuff works by default. Just set the url of your webservice and the request body payload) and go. In the callback you do the above and are fine.

Give it a try at 
https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

And inside your html after including the script resource for jquery in the header.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
 // your code goes here

}); </script>
```

To code your JQuery / JS.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header" id="content-wrapper">
            <h1>
                Dashboard <small>${userType} </small>
            </h1>
        </section>

    </div>
```